# Getting “Object deserialize error” on JSON stream after adding spring security

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, postman

I am using Postman to test REST calls passing JSON. Gets, puts, and posts all worked until I added spring security for logging in. After that, gets work, but posts and puts do not.

```
Post    http://localhost:8000/json/equipments
```

Headers

```
Accept              application/json
Content-type        application/json
Authorization       Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJwYXRyaWNrIiwiZXhwIjoxNDk5NzM3MzY1fQ.WWRampCM1C0QxA5IaTbqLWRHyeAJiLF8bxCBZBDbVbNjpANf1cDQIvUegEmP828kHJrkB6gQ0-zxauZe4cdlTQ
```

Body

```
{
    "field1": "field1",
    "field2": "field2"
}
```

Postman returns

```
{
        "timestamp": 1498874735373,
        "status": 400,
        "error": "Bad Request",
        "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException",
"message": "Could not read document: Object deserialize error\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5581e87c; line: 4, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object deserialize error\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5581e87c; line: 4, column: 1]",
    "path": "/json/equipments"
}
```

The log from mvn spring-boot:run returns

```
2017-06-30 20:12:54.552  WARN 42929 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Object deserialize error
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@166666cb; line: 4, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object deserialize error
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@166666cb; line: 4, column: 1]
2017-06-30 20:12:54.553  WARN 42929 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Object deserialize error
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@166666cb; line: 4, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Object deserialize error
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@166666cb; line: 4, column: 1]
```

I have found a number of similar errors online, but none like this one. They're usually a problem with a missing constructor or something. It worked just fine before securing the application, and I can’t see anything wrong with the data. Any idea? I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Which security mechanism are you using? httpBasic or formLogin? did you pass the correct credentials within your HTTP request to your controllers?

Comment: Actually both. FormLogin for web pages, and httpBasic for JSON. It's a Spring ROO 2.0 app, so a lot of the code is hidden. I successfully login on both sides. So the JSON calls work for gets after I call /jsonlogin and then pass the JWT token, and even puts and posts are authenticated or it I don't think it would even try to read the body of the message. Does that sound right to you? I'm new to JSON, JWT, Spring Security, and Spring Boot.

Comment: I would start by picking the correct security mechanism and use it, but not both.

Comment: It is both a web site and providing REST calls for a mobile device application. Can I use JWT for web pages? I didn't think that was possible. I'll research that.

Comment: It doesn't look like that will work. JWT is JSON only.